# Convert Pixel / array position to global coordinates Python

Tags: gdal, coordinates, array

I am trying to convert positions in a raster representing a .tif to the corresponding global coordinates. Converting the whole array to a tif and load it to QGIS everything is referenced fine, but using the below calculation method for single points there is a slight offset (to east-north-east in the resulting coordinates....

raster.tif uses ETRS 89 UTM Zone 32N

Does anyone has an idea?

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal, osr
import numpy as np


raster = gdal.Open("rasters/raster.tif")
raster_array = np.array(raster.ReadAsArray())


def pixel2coord(x, y):
     xoff, a, b, yoff, d, e = raster.GetGeoTransform()
     xp = a * x + b * y + xoff
     yp = d * x + e * y + yoff
     return(xp, yp)


print(pixel2coords(500,598))
```

Comment: I don't think it will solve your problem based on the direction of your incorrect displacement, but if you want the coordinate at the center of the pixels you should add 0.5 to your x and y variables.

Comment: Indeed this doesnt solve this my problem because the shift is about at least 200 cells in x direction and a bit in y direction. Thanks for that hint !

Comment: is it because i use a projected reference system?

Comment: How do you know they're off ~200 cells? I assume you're using a GIS to display the coordinates and the raster.tif. Does the GIS know the CRS of your coordinates, and is the GIS map in those coordinates? The formula you're using to convert is general and works for projected and unprojected CRSs, I believe.

Comment: yeah i used a configured QGIS and ArcGIS to check.. and also this site: https://www.koordinaten-umrechner.de/

Comment: How do you know you're off 200 cells? Can you show an image?

Comment: i have no easy way to show you because at the moment it is in a big piece of code, but the points are like 20meters from what i expect them to be... maybe i should write a simple test for this first...

Comment: But you have all the code already written in your post! Just do plt.imshow(raster_array) and plt.plot(500,598) to show the expected position, then do a screengrab from your GIS to show the resulting position.

Comment: plt.plot(500,598) gives me an empty diagram with x,y = 500, 598

Comment: Did you do the plt.imshow(raster_array) command first?